# undefined symbol "_Z14tf_git_versionv" in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, swig, undefined-symbol

I Built tensroflow R0.10 with bazel 0.3.1 then generated python whl file with no error. 
But, I'm getting this error. 
Is there any way to fix this?

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: _Z14tf_git_versionv
```

Comment: Could you try running ./configure?

Comment: Ok, I closed this issue, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5295 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We think that there was an issue in earlier versions. Please try to upgrade. The current version is 0.11rc2.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5295